# ASP.Net TO SQL Querying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following problem:

**Business Problem:** I have over 500 ETF's around the world categorized into different types (Region of the world, Capital type (small cap/large cap) etc which are different fields in a SQL database.

**Coding Problem:** I am able to show the entire list of ETF's, sort them etc. The problem lies in creating 5 different tables (5 regions of the world) on the same web page. In the SQL World it would be a simple

```
Select * from ETF where RegionDS = 'Europe'
```

**Where I am Today:**  I am able to query the database and retrieve all the ETF's and show them successfully on the page, but am not able to filter them in any way.   Here is the M/V/C  for just one table.  Hopefully someone can piece it together for me.

MODEL

```
namespace SmartAdminMvc.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public partial class ETF
    {
        [Key]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public System.DateTime TodaysDate { get; set; }
        public string  SubSectorDS { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RANK { get; set; }
        public string RegionDS { get; set; }
```

VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartAdminMvc.Models.ETF>

     <table id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
          <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RANK)</th>
          <th> <a title=@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Symbol)> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Symbol)  </a> </th>
          <th> <a title=@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TodaysDate)>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TodaysDate) </a> </th>
          <th> <a title=@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SectorDS)>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SectorDS) </a> </th>
          <th> <a title=@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegionDS)>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegionDS) </a> </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
          @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(item => item.RANK).Take(50))
          {
            if (item.RegionDS == "Europe")
              {
                <tr>
                <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RANK) </td>
                <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Symbol) </td>
                <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TodaysDate) </td>
                <td align="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SectorDS) </td>
                <td align="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegionDS) </td>
                </tr>
              }
        }
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SmartAdminMvc.Models;

namespace SmartAdminMvc.Controllers
{
    public class ETFsController : Controller
    {
        private QlikEntities db = new QlikEntities();

        // GET: vDailyPickSummaryTotals
        public ActionResult ETFWorld()
        {
            return View(db.ETFs.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: You are *still* in the SQL world. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, this is an Entity Framework question. Use LINQ and `where` or the `Where(...)` extension method to filter rows. Ordering and paging should be performed by the database as well, not the view

Comment: I cant seem to get my head out of SQL... ;-) Ill research the LINQ process. Thanks.

Comment: You are *already* using it in your Model. Use it with `db.ETFS` instead, ie `db.ETFS.Where(etf=>etf.RegionDS = "Europe").OrderBy(etf=>etf.RANK).Take(50).ToList();`

Comment: So are you saying that it should be  @foreach (var item in db.ETFS.Where(ETF=>ETF.RegionDS = "Europe").OrderBy(etf=>etf.RANK).Take(50).ToList());

Comment: No, it should be `public ActionResult ETFWorld() {return View( db.ETFS.Where(ETF=>ETF.RegionDS = "Europe").OrderBy(etf=>etf.RANK).Take(50).ToList()));}`. The *controller* is the one that's loading the data, not the view. If you want to return differelt lists per region, execute different queries in the controller and return the resulsts as separate properties in the model

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're taking the top 50 from the whole list, and then trying to filter out by region. But, this will only return the matches in those 50 records, if any. Instead, do the filter first:

```
      <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model.Where(w => w.RegionDS == "Europe").OrderBy(item => item.RANK).Take(50))
      {
            <tr>
            <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RANK) </td>
            <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Symbol) </td>
            <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TodaysDate) </td>
            <td align="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SectorDS) </td>
            <td align="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegionDS) </td>
            </tr>
      }
      </tbody>
```

**EDIT:**

If you're only displaying a subset of the records you could create a ViewModel such as this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ETF> EuropeETFs {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<ETF> AsiaETFs {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
vm.EuropeETFs = db.ETFs.Where(w => w.RegionDS == "Europe").OrderBy(item => item.RANK).Take(10);
....
```

Change the model type of your View to MyViewModel, then:

```
      <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model.EuropeETFs)
      {
            <tr>
            <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RANK) </td>
            <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Symbol) </td>
            <td align="right"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TodaysDate) </td>
            <td align="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SectorDS) </td>
            <td align="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegionDS) </td>
            </tr>
      }
      </tbody>
```

Comment: By that time it's too late. The controller has already loaded the entire database

Comment: True, but it depends if you want to display them all on the page anyway- the question stated that all 5 tables would be displayed on the same web page.

Comment: Correct.   I want to display lets say 10 records for Europe, 20 records for US, 10 for Asia, etc.

Comment: OK, if it's only a subset, you do want to filter in your controller - answer updated

Comment: Thanks.  Almost there i think.... just one error message on the @foreach (var item in Model.EuropeETFs) line...  does not contain a definition for 'EuropeETFs' and no extension method 'EuropeETFs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SmartAdminMvc.Models.MyViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In your view make sure you are setting the model type as '@model MyViewModel' not '@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>'

Comment: Yep. Did that... to no avail.... so my status right now is: Controller having a ActionResult index() that has the following:   MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
            vm.EuropeETFs = db.ETFs.Where(w => w.RegionDS == "Europe").OrderBy(item => item.RANK).Take(50);
            return View(vm.EuropeETFs.ToList());

Comment: What i meant to say... Tried that... unfortunately to no avail either.  Looks like a different error message now... SmartAdminMvc.Models.MyViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'EuropeETFs' and no extension method 'EuropeETFs' accepting a first argument of type 'SmartAdminMvc.Models.MyViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?... Sorry to be dense... just trying to learn this new world.   U guys have been helpful!

Comment: Ah, just return the whole view model - return View(vm);